# How to make divs take the uppermost and leftmost positions available

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to stitch together an image that is divided into several smaller images. I thought if I just floated everything left, they would fall together nicely so long as I declared the divs in the correct order. The full image is 999 pixels wide and 471 pixels tall, so my first attempt was this CSS:

```css
#ImageWrapper{
  background-color: #efefef;
  width: 999px;
  height: 471px;
  float:left;
}

#div1{
  background-color: #777;
  width: 258px;
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
}

#div2{
  background-color: #999;
  width: 678px;
  height: 37px;
  float: left;
}

#div3{
  background-color: #bbb;
  width: 63px;
  height: 471px;
  float: left;
}

#div4{
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="ImageWrapper">
  <div id="div1">1</div>
  <div id="div2">2</div>
  <div id="div3">3</div>
  <div id="div4">4</div>
</div>
```

And then I just declare the divs within the wrapper div in that order, and hoped it would end up looking like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4vPG.jpg. Divs 1-3 work, but div 4 does not. I tried messing around with the position attribute, but that didn't help either. Is there any way I can easily solve this, and have it work out like in my picture? Eventually I will have enough divs to fill the whole wrapper div, I just wanted to test as I went along.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `position: relative` to #ImageWrapper and then add the following to #div4:

```
  position:absolute;
  left: 258px;
  top: 37px;
```

Bear in mind this isn't responsive at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
#div4{
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  float: right;
  background-color:#b2f7;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:37px;
  margin-left:258px;
}
```

so simply change `position:absolute` and then using height and width of div 1 and div 2 you can move to a position.

[JSFiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/abdulqayyum/u2c8rpba/)

Comment: The only problem is I'll have almost 700 separate divs filling the wrapper once I finish, and this method would be very difficult to keep correct.

Comment: You might need Jquery UI for that purpose see in Interactions and Utility-> Position for that purpose. Because on different screen div order may change and if you see fiddle, it would not be responsive. User will be looking off screen for content